# Multidimentionnal $_POST extract issue (only 1 value returned)

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array, append

I have an issue with this :

**PART OF MY FORM**

```
  <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" name="config_name[]" type="text" placeholder="Nom"/>
                             </div></div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" name="config_pname[]" type="text"  placeholder="Prénom"/>
                             </div></div></div>
                                 <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" name="config_phone[]" type="text" placeholder="Numéro de mobile"/>
                             </div></div></div>
                                 <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" name="config_mail[]" type="text" placeholder="Adresse Mail"/>
                             </div></div></div>
<?php 
    $glprt_type = "dx";
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="config_'.strtolower($glprt_type).'[][]" value="'.$glprt_type.' '.$glprt_subtype.' '.$glprt_name.'"><b style="font-size: 12px;"> '.$glprt_type.' '.$glprt_subtype.' - '.$glprt_name.'</b> <br>'; ?>
```

**PHP PROCESS**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['config_pname']); $i++) {
echo $_POST['config_type'][$i].'<br />';
                echo  date('Y-m-d').'<br />';
                echo  $_POST['config_pname'][$i].'<br />';
                echo  $_POST['config_name'][$i].'<br />';
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['config_dx'][$i]); $j++) {
    echo $_POST['config_dx'][$j][$i].'<br />';
                    }
            }
```

The point is that I only get the first $_POST['config_dx'] record even if I have 3 sent througt POST Method.

What am I doing wrong ?
1/ `echo count($_POST['config_dx'][$i]` returns "1"

2/ if I replace in the loop

`echo $_POST['config_dx'][$j][$i].'<br />';`

by

`echo $_POST['config_dx'][0][$i].'<br />';
echo $_POST['config_dx'][1][$i].'<br />';
echo $_POST['config_dx'][2][$i].'<br />';`

my 3 results apperas so the loop seems not to loop :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried removing one of your `[ ]` in the input name?

Comment: Why are you using ** on the field name ?

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane I need it because i can have multiple config_dx for one config. Also In my case I can Create multiple config form BY using wrappers

Comment: @Vidal it was just a mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove the [$i] in your second for loop.

Like this:

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['config_dx']); $j++)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Grat !I spend all the ast night to search and I thought I already tested your solution but seems not :) Thanks a lot !